# Receiving null output for tdd url test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

When I run junit tests on my project I receive the following error when trying to test that my project can build a url correctly.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong below is the trace of the failed test run as well as the distancematrixconnection class and test class.  It is producing a blank output when trying to compile the url string.

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=albany&destinations=albany%20in&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial]](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=albany&destinations=albany%20in&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial%5d)> but was:<[]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at edu.bsu.cs222.gascalculator.tests.GoogleUrlTests.testAlbanyNYtoAlbanyINURL(GoogleUrlTests.java:26)

```
public class GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection
{
String startLocation;
String endLocation;
final String urlString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" + startLocation +"&destinations=" + endLocation +"&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial";


private static String XMLFile;

public String makeXMLFile(String start, String end) throws IOException
{
    startLocation = start;
    endLocation = end;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));

    for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = 
            reader.readLine())
    {
        setXMLFile(line);
    }

    return getXMLFile();
}
//  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
//      GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection c = new GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection();
//  }
public static String getXMLFile() {
    return XMLFile;
}
public static void setXMLFile(String xMLFile) {
    XMLFile = xMLFile;
}

public boolean doesPageExist() {
    if(XMLFile == null)
        return true;
    else    
        return false;
}
}
```

---

```
public class GoogleUrlTests {
private GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection urlString = new GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection();
private String generatedUrl = "";
private String actualUrl = "";

@Test
public void testAlbanyNYtoAlbanyINURL() throws IOException {
    generatedUrl = urlString.makeXMLFile("albany", "albany+in");
    actualUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=albany&destinations=albany%20in&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial";
    Assert.assertEquals(actualUrl, generatedUrl);
}

@Test
public void testLosAngelesToNewYorkURL() throws IOException {

    generatedUrl = urlString.makeXMLFile("losangeles", "newyork");
    actualUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=losangeles&destinations=newyork&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial";
    Assert.assertEquals(actualUrl, generatedUrl);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code returns the last line of whatever comes back from the HTTP request.  So it looks like there's a blank line at the end.  I guess you intended your code to do something other than this.  Please clarify what you were expecting.

Comment: You're comparing the URL `generatedUrl` to the last line read from the url when you open and read it.

Comment: No, @deanosaur, he's comparing the content of the `actualUrl` variable to the last line read.

Comment: @DavidWallace -- you're right, `generatedUrl` is the last line read from `actualUrl`. `makeXMLFile` is not creating a URL string, which is what the test seems to assume, instead its reading lines from a url.

Comment: i guess there's a need for the OP to clarify his question.

Comment: I just want it to run the url string and replace the variables startLocation and endLocation with the places in the test and make sure that it matches the actual url in the test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your test cases and your code in `makeXMLFile`, I'm confused of what you are really trying to do here.

If you want to pass you tests, then I think this code will do that for you. You can use `URLEncoder` to properly encode your URL string.

```
public class GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection
{

    public String makeXMLFile(String start, String end) throws IOException
    {
        return "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" + URLEncoder.encode(start) +"&destinations=" + URLEncoder.encode(end) +"&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial";    
    }
}
```

**Otherwise**, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I am trying to get the test to pass, but the GoogleDistanceMatrixConnection class is written to make the connection and save it as a url string if that makes much sense.  The parsing and tests is all very new to me.

Comment: @DanB In that sense, the test that you've written doesn't match the method that you've written.  You've written a test for a method that builds a URL, but doesn't actually visit it.  You've written a method that builds a URL, then visits it, reads the response, and returns the last line of the response.  If all you're trying to do at this point is make the test pass, then this answer is the correct one.

Comment: @DanB what is it really that you want to do?

Comment: I just want it to run the url string and replace the variables startLocation and endLocation with the places in the test and make sure that it matches the actual url in the test case

Comment: Additional edit I was able to put the public string makexmlfile into the googleurltests class and delete the urlstring. at the start of each generated url and they worked thank you for the help and sorry for the confusing question